# Apply "vector" to Point or LatLng in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

Drawing e.g. a 4km radius circle on a Leaflet map is dead simple. However, labelling that circle (without plugins) is not that simple anymore. The following fiddle somewhat works, but the `4km` label dances around as you change zoom levels:

https://jsfiddle.net/svoop/y1jqoxu7/

Any idea how I could improve this?

(Please don't suggest any plugins unless they are very well maintained and ready for Leaflet 1.0, thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label in your example is offset because you are calculating meters/pixel in an unreliable way. There is no guarantee that `centerLatLng` falls exactly at the center of a pixel on the map. In fact, it is almost guaranteed *not* to, so `map.containerPointToLatLng([centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y])` will not produce the same coordinates as `centerLatLng`, and your distances will be off by as much as 50%. You will get a more satisfactory result by calculating your `metersPerPixelY` like this:

```
metersPerPixelY = map.containerPointToLatLng([centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y + 1]).distanceTo(map.containerPointToLatLng([centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y]));
```

However, there will still be some error with this method, as the true meters/pixel varies with latitude. My suggestion would be to use [leaflet-geodesy](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-geodesy) to create ~circular polygons and place your labels based on the bounds of those polygons. `L.circle` objects do not provide any method to get their bounds, so the plugin is necessary. The following will create a 144-sided polygon (fine enough to look circular at any scale) and place a label on the northern edge of the circle:

```
var circ = LGeo.circle(centerLatLng, radiusMeters, {parts: 144}).addTo(map);
var labelLatLng = [circ.getBounds().getNorth(),centerLatLng[1]];
var labelUp = L.divIcon({ className: 'four', html: '4km' });
L.marker(labelLatLng, { icon: labelUp }).addTo(map);
```

This is certainly not the only way to get the label location you want, but it is relatively simple, and the plugin works fine with Leaflet 1.0. Here's an example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/a022bL4q/

Comment: Very nice, thanks for the sample code! I've achieved good results by calculating the label position with [geodesy](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy), however, wrapping the API to make it compatible with Leaflet is not very elegant, so I prefer your solution.

Comment: I just saw that Leaflet 1.0 circles do support `getBounds()`, so it should be possible to do this without the plugin, once Mapbox.js is updated to play nice with Leaflet 1.0.

Comment: It looks like the `getBounds()` method for circles [still has some bugs](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4582) to work out.